# R: Creating Random Samples From Entries in Neighboring Row

Tags: r, function, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following data set:

```
my_data = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), n = c(15,3,51,8,75))
```

I want to create a new variable that generates a single random integer for each row based on the corresponding value of "n". I tried to do this with the following code:

```
my_data$rand = sample.int(my_data$n,1)
```

But this is not working (the same random number is repeated 5 times).

I also tried to define a function to this:

```
my_function <- function(x){sample.int(x,1)}

transform(my_data, new_column= my_function(my_data$n) )
```

But this is also not working (the same random number is again repeated 5 times)..

In the end, I am trying to achieve something like this :

```
my_data$rand = c(sample.int(15,1), sample.int(3,1), sample.int(51,1), sample.int(8,1), sample.int(75,1))
```

**Can someone please show me how to do this for larger datasets without having to manually specify each "sample.int" command?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "based on value of `n`" what do you mean by that exactly? Based on `n` how?

**Guess#1**: at each row, you want to draw one random number with possible values being 1 to `n`.
**Guess#2**: at each row, you want to draw `n` random numbers for possible values between 0 and 1.

Second option is harder, but option #1 can be done with a loop:

```
my_data = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), n = c(15,3,51,8,75))
my_data$rand = NA

set.seed(123)
for(i in 1:nrow(my_data)){
  my_data$rand[i] = sample(1:(my_data$n[i]), size = 1)
}

my_data
```

```
  id  n rand
1  1 15   15
2  2  3    3
3  3 51   51
4  4  8    6
5  5 75   67
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sapply` to go over all rows in `my_data`, and generate one `sample.int` per iteration.

```
my_data$rand <- sapply(1:nrow(my_data), function(x) sample.int(my_data[x, 2], 1))

  id  n rand
1  1 15    7
2  2  3    2
3  3 51   28
4  4  8    6
5  5 75    9
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! In the second row, I noticed that than n = 3 and rand = 12, ... rand > n. I am trying to make it such that "rand" can never be greater than "n". In this case, I would have wanted " sample.int(3,1)" . Is it possible to fix this? Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: @stats_noob Yes of course, I somehow mis-read your question previously. See my update :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this efficiently by a single call to `runif()`, multiplying by `n`, and rounding up:

```
transform(my_data, rand = ceiling(runif(n) * n))

  id  n rand
1  1 15   13
2  2  3    1
3  3 51   41
4  4  8    1
5  5 75    9
```